# How can I apply a patch I got from email but one change at a time?

Tags: git, patch

I have a patch file. I can apply the patch of course using `git am` (although for some reason it does not complete successfully on *very simple changes*)

However what I want to do now is to select which changes in the patch I want to apply an which I want to skip one by one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If there are not too many changes you want to opt out, then what you could do is apply the path first, and then rollback those changes you do not want to keep. And afterwards you can amend the applied commit to rewrite it to include your reversals.

This could for example look like this:

```sh
# Apply patch
$ git am <some-file>

# Use interactive checkout to undo particular changes from the applied patch
# (Note that you will have to apply those hunks that _undo_ the undesired changes)
$ git checkout -p HEAD~1

# Add those reverting changes to the index
$ git add -u

# Amend the applied commit to incorporate your reversals
$ git commit --amend
```

Instead of using `git checkout -p` you could of course also undo those changes manually. For larger change sets this might be easier if there are just very few things you want to undo.

Alternatively, you could also apply the patch using `git apply` which does not commit the changes, so you can review the changes first and unstage the undesired changes. Note that this will not reuse the commit message and author information from the original patch though, so you would have to rewrite that (and the commit would be attributed to yourself instead of the original author).

Comment: I did the last option but now I have a bunch of unstaged files that even though are not commited are still created. How do I eliminate them?

Comment: If they are tracked by Git (i.e. there are pending changes), then you can undo those using `git checkout -- .`, or alternatively using `git checkout -p` if you want to decide (again) for each change. If these are new files Git doesn’t know about yet, you will have to delete them manually from your working directory.

Comment: thanks. So for these new file, the `git checkout --` doesn't work, does it?

Comment: Unfortunately not, `git checkout` only checks out files that are already known to Git, overwriting the current state in the working directory. Untracked files are not affected.